# caret::train Duplicating predictor variables

Tags: r, caret, rpart

In R, when I try to build a rpart CTree with a caret using:

```
tree <- caret::train(LoanStatus ~ ., data = home_training, method = "rpart")
```

Everything is fine until I try to predict:

```
predictions <- predict(tree$finalModel, newdata = home_validation, type = "class")
```

Which gives me the error: `Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'Gender1' not found`

Then, I notice that R has duplicated some of my predictor variables (they are factors):

`varImp(tree)` outputs:

```
ApplicantIncome    2.218022
CoapplicantIncome    4.564288
Education1    6.214741
LoanAmount    7.183707
LoanAmountTerm    1.554240
Married1    6.895146
PropertyArea1    5.806154
Gender1    0.000000
Dependents1    0.000000
Dependents2    0.000000
Dependents3    0.000000
SelfEmployed1    0.000000
PropertyArea2    0.000000
```

Which contains a lot of duplicates.

If I do the same using `rpart` directly with: `tree2 <- rpart(LoanStatus ~ ., home_training, method = "class")`

Does not gives me any errors and also has no duplicate variables.

I wanted to do it using a caret, because it allows to use cross validation.

How can I fix this?